# SWAP CRITICAL - 100% free (0 MB out of 0 MB)?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, memory, swap

ANy ideas how to address this issue ....I am on ubuntu 10.04 on amazon ec2 here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQtGc.png)

Comment: A little more info would help :)

Comment: what is it i can provide...I have ssh access

Comment: You saw it from where? Nagios's check_swap plugin?

Comment: its in the image in my question

Comment: yes it was from the plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me that's just a bug or fake warning from the interface you are looking at. It says that the problem is critical because you have no swap space available and ironically it says that 100% is free because 0% is used; BUT the fact is that it seems that you haven't swap at all.

Do you really need swap? if not, you can ignore that warning.

Comment: I probably dont need it but what is it to begin with and do most sites use it

Comment: nevermind i found this http://serverfault.com/questions/48486/what-is-swap-memory