# How to check what is on a specific partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition

I was looking at my harddrive with gparted, and noticed a small partition at /dev/sda5.  I cannot cd into that folder directly, but I was hoping to find out what is on that partition.  How do I do this?  Do I need to mount it?

Comment: can you post the output of `fdisk -l`?

Comment: No output from disk -l

Comment: Run it as root. Also give us the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`.

Comment: [It's swap.](http://serverfault.com/questions/48486/what-is-swap-memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading everything you've posted, it's swap space. You cannot mount it, and there is nothing interesting to see there anyway. All that it contains is memory pages that needed to be moved from RAM to disk to make room for actively running processes.

[Read Here](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8208-all-about-linux-swap-space) for more info on swap space.

Comment: Right, what Zypher said. If the information is needed for some kind of investigation, then processing the data in swap may actually be useful. If that's the case then @coffee needs to clarify his intent.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!  I am trying to figure out if I can remove this partition.  I am trying to extend my main partition, but this bit is in the way..

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, determine the file system type with `fsck -N /dev/sda5` or `file -s /dev/sda5` and mount by executing `mkdir /mnt/sda5 && mount -t <type> /dev/sda5 /mnt/sda5`.

Comment: using fsck "fsck.swap: not found".  Using file -s "no read permission"

Comment: You must run the command as root user.

Comment: Thanks.  It's a Linux/i386 swap file (new style).  Does this complicate things?  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount the partition to see what's inside. However, you can mount it read-only to prevent even accidentally changing anything. This is done like this

mount --read-only /dev/sda5 tmp

Comment: "/dev/sda5 looks like swapspace - not mounted"